# Transform complex svg shapes into a circle abstraction

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

SVGs are ugly please review my:

### [JSFIDDLE LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/matty0187/kw5peu40/1/)

**HTML:**

```
<svg version="1.1" class="overlap-svg" id="alaska"></svg>
<svg version="1.1" class="overlap-svg" id="grid"></svg>
```

**CSS:**

```
.overlap-svg {
    position: absolute;
    left:0;
    top: 0;
}
```

### **Question:**

**If we overlap these 2 svgs, What would the JS function be to highlight only the svg circles that have parts of alaska(red)in them  in them?**

*review description below for more info*

---

1. Let's say you have a complex shape like the outline of alaska.

[image]

2. Lets say you have another svg of a grid of circles:

[image]

---

**How do I transform this:**

[image]

**Into something like this:**

[image]

*the circle should be filled red if any portion of alaska(red) is inside the area of the circle.*

Again please review my JSFiddle link above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/grahampheath/8pee5zh2/5/)

[image: Example output, with resized canvas element overlayed.]
You can take the svg and load it into a canvas element. Take the element, and because it is a canvas element you can get an array of its pixels.

Your circle abstraction could be built by building the grid out of the pixels of an appropriately resized canvas.

First a helper: Grid Manager.

```
function GridManager(configIn) {
  var gm_ = {};

  gm_.config = {
    'gridWidth': 10,
    'gridHeight': 10,
    'gridCellWidth': 10,
    'gridCellHeight': 10,
    'gridHeight': 100,
    'dataSrc': []
  };

  // Load new config over defaults
  for (var property in configIn) {
    gm_.config[property] = configIn[property];
  }

  /** 
    * Creates an array using the module's config building a 2d data array 
    * from a flat array. Loops over GridManager.config.dataSrc
    * 
    * Render a checkerboard pattern:
    *   GridManager.config.dataSrc = ["#"," "]
    * 
    * Render you can load a image by passing in its full pixel array, 
    * provided image height and width match GridManager.config.gridHeight
    * and GridManager.config.gridWidth. 
    */
  gm_.createGridSrc = function() {
    var height = this.config.gridHeight;
    var width = this.config.gridWidth;
    var output = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < height; i++) {
      output[i] = [];

      for (var ii = 0; ii < width; ii++) {
        if (this.config.dataSrc !== undefined) {
          var dataSrc = this.config.dataSrc;
          output[i][ii] = dataSrc[i*width + ii % dataSrc.length];
        }
      }
    }
    return output;
  };

  /** 
    * Creates a SVG with a grid of circles based on
    * GridManager.config.dataSrc.
    * 
    * This is where you can customize GridManager output.
    */
  gm_.createSvgGrid = function() {
    var cellWidth = this.config.gridCellWidth;
    var cellHeight = this.config.gridCellHeight;
    var svgWidth = 1000;
    var svgHeight = 1000;
    var radius = 3
    var cellOffset = radius / 2;

    //create svg
    var xmlns = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg';
    var svgElem = document.createElementNS (xmlns, 'svg');
    svgElem.setAttributeNS (null, 'viewBox', '0 0 ' + svgWidth + ' ' + svgHeight);
    svgElem.setAttributeNS (null, 'width', svgWidth);
    svgElem.setAttributeNS (null, 'height', svgHeight);
    svgElem.style.display = 'block';

    //create wrapper path
    var g = document.createElementNS (xmlns, 'g');
    svgElem.appendChild (g);

    //create grid
    var data = this.createGridSrc();
    var count = 0;
    for (var i = data.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      for (var ii = data[i].length - 1; ii >= 0; ii--) {
        
        // This svgHeight and svgWidth subtraction here flips the image over
        // perhaps this should be accomplished elsewhere.
        var y = svgHeight - (cellHeight * i) - cellOffset;
        var x = svgWidth - (cellWidth * ii) - cellOffset;

        var cell = document.createElementNS (xmlns, 'circle');
        var template = data[i][ii];
        
        // Machine has averaged the amount of fill per pixel
        // from 0 - 255, so you can filter just the red pixels like this
        // over a certain strength.
        if (template[0] > 10 ) {
          cell.setAttributeNS (null, 'fill', '#ff0000');
          // Consider stashing refs to these in this.groups['red'] or something
          // similar
        } else {
          cell.setAttributeNS (null, 'fill', 'none');
        }

        cell.setAttributeNS (null, 'stroke', '#000000');
        cell.setAttributeNS (null, 'stroke-miterlimit', '#10');
        cell.setAttributeNS (null, 'cx', x);
        cell.setAttributeNS (null, 'cy', y);
        cell.setAttributeNS (null, 'r', radius);

        g.appendChild (cell);
      }
    }
    return svgElem;
  }
  return gm_;
}
```

And then in main.js

```
var wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper');

var mySVG = document.getElementById('alaska').outerHTML;

mySVG = mySVG.slice(0, 4) + ' height="100" ' + mySVG.slice(4);

// Create a Data URI based on the #alaska element.
var mySrc = 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,' + window.btoa(mySVG);

// Create a new image to do our resizing and capture our pixel data from.
var source = new Image();
source.onload = function() {

  var svgRasterStage = document.createElement('canvas');
  svgRasterStage.width = 1000;
  svgRasterStage.height = 1000;

  svgRasterStage.classList.add('hidden');

  // You may not need this at all, I didn't test it.
  wrapper.appendChild(svgRasterStage);

  // Get drawing context for the Canvas
  var svgRasterStageContext = svgRasterStage.getContext('2d');

  // Draw the SVG to the stage.
  svgRasterStageContext.drawImage(source, 0, 0);
  
  // We can now get array of rgba pixels all concatinated together:
  //    [ r, g, b, a, r, g, b, a,  (...)  r, g, b, a, r, g, b, a]
  var rgbaConcat = svgRasterStageContext.getImageData(0, 0, 100, 100).data;

  // Which sucks, so here's a way to convert them to pixels that we can 
  // use with GridManager.createSvgGrid.
  var pixels = [];
  var count = 0;
  
  // NOTE: this is a for with a weird step: i=i-4. i-4 is an infinte loop.
  // anything else just jumbles the pixels.
  for (var i = rgbaConcat.length - 1; i >= 0; i=i-4) {
    var r = rgbaConcat[i - 0];
    var g = rgbaConcat[i - 1];
    var b = rgbaConcat[i - 2];
    var a = rgbaConcat[i - 3];
    pixels.push([r, g, b, a]);
  }

  // We create our GridManager (finally).
  var gm = new GridManager({
    'gridWidth': 100,
    'gridHeight': 100,
    'dataSrc': pixels
  });
  
  // And let her rip!
  wrapper.appendChild(gm.createSvgGrid());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried to quick-solve this issue, and did some research, but still **it is not finished / complete** (you can finish it in your fina implementation).

You need to have a function that check *If a point is inside a path*.
I found 2 libraries in JS: **Raphael** and **SnapSVG**.

I forked and edited your JSFiddle, and *fast-tried* to solve it. My first attempt was with [SnapSVG's function](http://snapsvg.io/docs/#Snap.path.isPointInside) but it returned me a lesser-than-expected result than [Raphael's function](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Raphael.isPointInsidePath).

Open the fiddle and check: https://jsfiddle.net/edmundo096/7sjLb956/4/.
Beware that the scale of 2 ***will slow your browser***, although I used it to see a correct result but takes time to see something (mobile browsers may hang up).

```
var alaska = $('#alaska');
var grid = $('#grid');
var path =  alaska.find('path').first().attr('d');

grid.children().each(function(){
    var circle = $(this);
    var scale = 2;

    // SnapSVG version: var isInside = Snap.path.isPointInside(path, 
    var isInside = Raphael.isPointInsidePath(path, 
                        circle.attr('cx') * scale, 
                        circle.attr('cy') * scale);
    if (isInside) {
        circle.attr('fill', 'blue');
    }
});
```

(I used jQuery, and 2 external resources: Raphael and SnapSvg from Cloudflare CDN)

As you can see on the next image, it generates a kind of dot map, but still you need to correct the mapping, placement, scale, etc. of the Path.

**Raphael first quick-try result:**

[image: A quick result of the Raphael function]

**SnapSVG first quick-try result:**
[image: A quick result of the SnapSvg function]

You can cache your result; save the resulted map in a JSON map object, and then load it separately **to save the calculation Time** from this **complex Paths**.

Hope it can help you.

Answer (score 0):

You could take the circle center coordinates and use something like Raphael's `isPointInsidePath()` function to test if it is inside the map path.

http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Raphael.isPointInsidePath